# Save or export SVG as CMYK pixel data

Tags: windows, gratis, svg, inkscape

I have an SVG graphic made with Inkscape which is designed for printing, i.e. I use CMYK colors (our corporate colors). I now need to provide this drawing as pixel data for the printing lab.

The problem:

Unfortunately, Inkscape only exports to PNG, which uses RGB colors. The PDF export does not seem to use CMYK colors.

I have tried:

I found a plugin called [ExportPDFCMYK](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExportPDFCMYK), but it's available for Linux only. I'm looking for a Windows solution.

Ok, so what I need is

- an Inkscape plugin or standalone tool
- that reads the SVG
- and exports it to a CMYK compatible pixel data format (e.g. TIFF)
- while restricting the output to the page size (there may be items overlapping the page boundary which I don't want to be exported)
- and is gratis
- and supports large files and resolutions (150 dpi, ~30.000 pixels)

Comment: The usual workflow involves postprocessing your SVG with Scribus. Examples [here](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/getting-cmyk-colors-from-inkscape-to-scribus), [here](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/06/05/creating-cmyk-prepress-pdfs-with-inkscape-and-scribus/), [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60200/inkscape-svg-%E2%86%92-print-ready-eps-pdf-workflow), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNkWXwk_H8o).

Comment: @Juancho: ok, thanks for all the links. Seems available for Windows. I'll give it a try (scheduled for Tuesday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this post](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/06/05/creating-cmyk-prepress-pdfs-with-inkscape-and-scribus/) you can use Scribus with Inkscape to prepare press ready pdf file.

[Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) is another free, gratis, open source & cross platform program.

The steps are basically:

1. Find out the colour profile that your printing service uses, [download](http://www.eci.org/de/downloads) and install it.
2. Set Scribus to use the same colour profile
3. Load the svg file, *needs to be single layer and all text converted to paths*
4. Remove unused colours
5. Convert remaining colours
6. Save as sla
7. Export to pdf